# SQLAlchemy/Flask not showing records in table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Currently programming a small app in Flask for school.

I made a DB and the I've put some data in there, simple nothing to worry about.

I created a query to get all of the records out and show them in a html table,
all I get is `<player 1`> or `<player 2>`, but not the actual name or player ID.

In the route:

```
@main.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
   from .models import Players

   playerdetails = Players.query.all()
   return render_template('index.html', name=current_user.name, playerdetails=playerdetails)
```

the HTML:

```
    <tbody>
        {% for players in playerdetails %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ playerdetails[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ playerdetails[2] }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

This is what I have in the database:

[image]

This is what the website shows:

[image]

I can add more players, and the table gets bigger. and if I change it to `{{ playerdetails[3] }}`
it'll just show `< players 4 >`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I had to do `{{ players.name }}` and  `{{ players.player_number }}`

small mistake that can really grind your gears for hours.